# How to reduce memory useage when solving system of 9 coupled PDE

Tags: memory, wolfram-mathematica, physics, pde

I have a system of coupled partial differential equations as shown in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPpmr.png).

[system of equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPpmr.png)

If one writes the equations componentwise, one gets nine equations. 
For simplicity, one can set $\rho$ and $h$ constant.

I put the equations into a mathematica notebook and used 'NDSolve'.
I counted a number of 268 derivatives in the system. However, I didnt find more than 87 conditions that made sence.

When I run the notebook, I get the message

```
NDSolve::pdord: Some of the functions have zero differential order, so the equations will be solved as a system of differential-algebraic equations. >>

LinearSolve::sing: Matrix SparseArray[Automatic,<<3>>] is singular. >>

NDSolve::mconly: For the method IDA, only machine real code is available. Unable to continue with complex values or beyond floating-point exceptions. >>
```

I understand the first error: There is no time derivative in $\phi$, so the system is strictly speaking a differential-algebraic-system.

After about 40 minutes, mathematica says:

```
No more memory available.
Mathematica kernel has shut down.
Try quitting other applications and then retry.
```

What can I change to reduce the memory cost, or -- better -- what can I change to solve the system more elegant?

Here is the mathematica code:

```
NDSolve[{
  eqn1 == 0,
  eqn2 == 0,
  eqn3 == 0,
  eqn4 == 0,
  eqn5 == 0,
  eqn6 == 0,
  eqn7 == 0,
  eqn8 == 0,
  eqn9 == 0,

  (*Initial Conditions*)
  T[0, x, y, z] == 300,
  p[0, x, y, z] == 101300,
  phi[t, x, y, z] == 75 x /. t -> 0,
  u1[0, x, y, z] == 0,
  (*   ect...   *)

  (*BOUNDARY CONDITIONS*)
  phi[t, x, y, z] == 0 /. x -> 0,
  phi[t, x, y, z] == 750 /. x -> 10,
  phi[t, x, y, z] == 75 x /. y -> 0,
  phi[t, x, y, z] == 75 x /. y -> 10,
  phi[t, x, y, z] == 75 x /. z -> 0,
  phi[t, x, y, z] == 75 x /. z -> 10,
  \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(y\)]\(phi[t, x, y, z]\)\) == 0 /. 
   y -> 0,
  \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(y\)]\(phi[t, x, y, z]\)\) == 0 /. 
   y -> 10,
  (*  ect.....  *)

  },
 {p, u1, u2, u3, T, phi, a1, a2, a3},
 {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, {z, 0, 10}
 ]
```

And here is the Latex-code for the equations:

```
\begin{align}   
        %%% first
        \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}  + \vec{u} \cdot \nabla \rho + \rho \nabla \cdot \vec{u} &=0 \\
        %%% second
        \rho \frac{\partial \vec{u}}{\partial t} 
        + \rho \vec{u} \cdot \nabla \vec{u} \pm \nabla p 
        + \nabla \cdot \left[- \mu \left( \nabla \vec{u} + \nabla \vec{u}^t \right) \right] \nonumber
        \\ - 
        \left[ \sigma   
        \left( - \nabla \phi - \frac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial t} \right)
        + \vec{u} \times (\nabla \times \vec{A}) \right]
        %
         \times \left[ \nabla \times \vec{A} \right]
        &= \vec{0} \\
         %%% third
        \rho \frac{\partial h}{\partial t}
        + \rho \vec{u} \cdot \nabla h
        + \nabla \cdot \nabla T
        - \frac{\partial p}{\partial t}
        - \overset{.}{Q_j} + \overset{.}{Q_r}
        &= 0 \\
        %%% fourth
        \nabla \cdot \left[ \sigma  
        \left( - \nabla \phi - \frac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial t} \right)
         + \vec{u} \times (\nabla \times \vec{A}) \right] &= 0 \\
        %%% fifth
        \frac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial t} + \nabla \phi - \vec{u} \times \nabla \times \vec{A} - \eta \nabla ^2 \vec{A} &= \vec{0}
    \end{align}
```

I add the plain mathematica code here:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]


kB = N[ 8.6*10^-5 ];
AG = N[1.2*10^6 ];
mu0 = 1.257*10^(-6);

sigma = N[20.];
eta = 1/(mu0 * sigma); 
rho = N[1.];
h = N[1672000.];


r = 1/ 287.058 ;

mu = N[1.];

kappah = N[5.];

cp = N[2.4];



lbb = NDSolve[{
   0 == D[rho, t] + u1[t, x, y, z]*D[rho, x] + 
     u2[t, x, y, z]*D[rho, y] + u3[t, x, y, z]*D[rho, z] + 

     rho*(D[u1[t, x, y, z], x] + D[u2[t, x, y, z], y] + 
        D[u3[t, x, y, z], z]), 

       0 == 
    rho*D[u1[t, x, y, z], t] + 
     rho*u1[t, x, y, z]*D[u1[t, x, y, z], x] - D[p[t, x, y, z], x] - 
     mu*D[D[u1[t, x, y, z], x], x] - 
           mu*D[D[u1[t, x, y, z], y], y] - 
     mu*D[D[u1[t, x, y, z], z], z] - 
           (((-sigma)*D[phi[t, x, y, z], y] - 
          sigma*D[a2[t, x, y, z], t] + 
          u3[t, x, y, 
            z]*(D[a3[t, x, y, z], y] - D[a2[t, x, y, z], z]) - 

          u1[t, x, y, 
            z]*(D[a2[t, x, y, z], x] - D[a1[t, x, y, z], y]))*(D[
           a2[t, x, y, z], x] - D[a1[t, x, y, z], y]) - 
              ((-sigma)*D[phi[t, x, y, z], z] - 
          sigma*D[a3[t, x, y, z], t] + 
          u1[t, x, y, 
            z]*(D[a1[t, x, y, z], z] - D[a3[t, x, y, z], x]) - 

          u2[t, x, y, 
            z]*(D[a3[t, x, y, z], y] - D[a2[t, x, y, z], z]))*(D[
           a1[t, x, y, z], z] - D[a3[t, x, y, z], x])), 

       0 == 
    rho*D[u2[t, x, y, z], t] + 
     rho*u2[t, x, y, z]*D[u2[t, x, y, z], y] - D[p[t, x, y, z], y] - 
     mu*D[D[u2[t, x, y, z], x], x] - 
           mu*D[D[u2[t, x, y, z], y], y] - 
     mu*D[D[u2[t, x, y, z], z], z] - 
           (((-sigma)*D[phi[t, x, y, z], z] - 
          sigma*D[a3[t, x, y, z], t] + 
          u1[t, x, y, 
            z]*(D[a1[t, x, y, z], z] - D[a3[t, x, y, z], x]) - 

          u2[t, x, y, 
            z]*(D[a3[t, x, y, z], y] - D[a2[t, x, y, z], z]))*(D[
           a3[t, x, y, z], y] - D[a2[t, x, y, z], z]) - 
              (D[a2[t, x, y, z], x] - 
          D[a1[t, x, y, z], y])*((-sigma)*D[phi[t, x, y, z], x] - 
          sigma*D[a1[t, x, y, z], t] + 


          u2[t, x, y, 
            z]*(D[a2[t, x, y, z], x] - D[a1[t, x, y, z], y]) - 
          u3[t, x, y, 
            z]*(D[a1[t, x, y, z], z] - D[a3[t, x, y, z], x]))),

       0 == 
    rho*D[u3[t, x, y, z], t] + 
     rho*u3[t, x, y, z]*D[u3[t, x, y, z], z] - D[p[t, x, y, z], z] - 
     mu*D[D[u3[t, x, y, z], x], x] - 
           mu*D[D[u3[t, x, y, z], y], y] - 
     mu*D[D[u3[t, x, y, z], z], z] - 
           (((-sigma)*D[phi[t, x, y, z], x] - 
          sigma*D[a1[t, x, y, z], t] + 
          u2[t, x, y, 
            z]*(D[a2[t, x, y, z], x] - D[a1[t, x, y, z], y]) - 

          u3[t, x, y, 
            z]*(D[a1[t, x, y, z], z] - D[a3[t, x, y, z], x]))*(D[
           a1[t, x, y, z], z] - D[a3[t, x, y, z], x]) - 
              ((-sigma)*D[phi[t, x, y, z], y] - 
          sigma*D[a2[t, x, y, z], t] + 
          u3[t, x, y, 
            z]*(D[a3[t, x, y, z], y] - D[a2[t, x, y, z], z]) - 

          u1[t, x, y, 
            z]*(D[a2[t, x, y, z], x] - D[a1[t, x, y, z], y]))*(D[
           a3[t, x, y, z], y] - D[a2[t, x, y, z], z])), 


      0 == rho*D[h, t] + 
     rho*(u1[t, x, y, z]*D[h, x] + u2[t, x, y, z]*D[h, y] + 
        u3[t, x, y, z]*D[h, z]) + 

     kappah*(D[T[t, x, y, z], x, x] + D[D[T[t, x, y, z], y], y] + 
        D[D[T[t, x, y, z], z], z]) - D[p[t, x, y, z], t], 


      0 == D[
      sigma*(-D[phi[t, x, y, z], x] - D[a1[t, x, y, z], t]) + 
       u2[t, x, y, z]*(D[a2[t, x, y, z], x] - D[a1[t, x, y, z], y]) - 

       u3[t, x, y, z]*(D[a1[t, x, y, z], z] - D[a3[t, x, y, z], x]), 
      x] + D[sigma*(-D[phi[t, x, y, z], y] - D[a2[t, x, y, z], t]) + 

       u3[t, x, y, z]*(D[a3[t, x, y, z], y] - D[a2[t, x, y, z], z]) - 
       u1[t, x, y, z]*(D[a2[t, x, y, z], x] - D[a1[t, x, y, z], y]), 
      y] + 

     D[sigma*(-D[phi[t, x, y, z], z] - D[a3[t, x, y, z], t]) + 
       u1[t, x, y, z]*(D[a1[t, x, y, z], z] - D[a3[t, x, y, z], x]) - 

       u2[t, x, y, z]*(D[a3[t, x, y, z], y] - D[a2[t, x, y, z], z]), 
      z], 

       0 == 
    D[a1[t, x, y, z], t] + D[phi[t, x, y, z], x] - 
     u2[t, x, y, z]*(D[a2[t, x, y, z], x] - D[a1[t, x, y, z], y]) - 

     u3[t, x, y, z]*(D[a1[t, x, y, z], z] - D[a3[t, x, y, z], x]) - 
     eta*D[D[a1[t, x, y, z], x], x], 

       0 == 
    D[a2[t, x, y, z], t] + D[phi[t, x, y, z], y] - 
     u3[t, x, y, z]*(D[a3[t, x, y, z], y] - D[a2[t, x, y, z], z]) - 

     u1[t, x, y, z]*(D[a2[t, x, y, z], x] - D[a1[t, x, y, z], y]) - 
     eta*D[D[a2[t, x, y, z], y], y], 

       0 == 
    D[a3[t, x, y, z], t] + D[phi[t, x, y, z], z] - 
     u1[t, x, y, z]*(D[a1[t, x, y, z], z] - D[a3[t, x, y, z], x]) - 

     u2[t, x, y, z]*(D[a3[t, x, y, z], y] - D[a2[t, x, y, z], z]) - 
     eta*D[D[a3[t, x, y, z], z], z], T[0, x, y, z] == 300, 



   p[0, x, y, z] == 101300, 
   phi[t, x, y, z] == 75*x /. t -> 0, u1[0, x, y, z] == 0,
   u2[0, x, y, z] == 0, u3[0, x, y, z] == 0,
   a1[0, x, y, z] == 0, a2[0, x, y, z] == 0,
   a3[0, x, y, z] == 0, D[T[t, x, y, z], x] == 0 /. x -> 0,

   D[T[t, x, y, z], x] == 0 /. x -> 10, 
   D[T[t, x, y, z], y] == 0 /. y -> 0,
   D[T[t, x, y, z], y] == 0 /. y -> 10,
   D[T[t, x, y, z], z] == 0 /. z -> 0, 
   D[T[t, x, y, z], z] == 0 /. z -> 10,

   phi[t, x, y, z] == 0 /. x -> 0,
   phi[t, x, y, z] == 750 /. x -> 10,
   phi[t, x, y, z] == 75*x /. y -> 0, 
   phi[t, x, y, z] == 75*x /. y -> 10,
   phi[t, x, y, z] == 75*x /. z -> 0,
   phi[t, x, y, z] == 75*x /. z -> 10, 
   D[phi[t, 0, y, z], x] == (-sigma^(-1))*0.5*AG*T[t, 0, y, z]^2*
     Exp[-4/(kB*T[t, 0, y, z])],
   D[phi[t, 10, y, z], x] == (-sigma^(-1))*0.5*AG*T[t, 10, y, z]^2*
    Exp[-4/(kB*T[t, 10, y, z])],
   D[phi[t, x, y, z], y] == 0 /. y -> 0, 
   D[phi[t, x, y, z], y] == 0 /. y -> 10, 
   D[phi[t, x, y, z], z] == 0 /. z -> 0, 
   D[phi[t, x, y, z], z] == 0 /. z -> 10, 

   p[t, x, y, z] == 101300 /. x -> 0,
   p[t, x, y, z] == 101300 /. x -> 10,
   p[t, x, y, z] == 101300 /. y -> 0,
   p[t, x, y, z] == 101300 /. y -> 10, 
   p[t, x, y, z] == 101300 /. z -> 0, 
   p[t, x, y, z] == 101300 /. z -> 10, u1[t, x, y, z] == 0 /. x -> 0, 
   u1[t, x, y, z] == 0 /. x -> 10, 

   D[u1[t, x, y, z], y] == 0 /. y -> 0,
   D[u1[t, x, y, z], y] == 0 /. y -> 10,
   D[u1[t, x, y, z], z] == 0 /. z -> 0, 
   D[u1[t, x, y, z], z] == 0 /. z -> 10,

   u2[t, x, y, z] == 0 /. x -> 0, 
   u2[t, x, y, z] == 0 /. x -> 10,
   D[u2[t, x, y, z], y] == 0 /. y -> 0, 
   D[u2[t, x, y, z], y] == 0 /. y -> 10,
   D[u2[t, x, y, z], z] == 0 /. z -> 0,
   D[u2[t, x, y, z], z] == 0 /. z -> 10, 

   u3[t, x, y, z] == 0 /. x -> 0, u3[t, x, y, z] == 0 /. x -> 10,
   D[u3[t, x, y, z], y] == 0 /. y -> 0,
   D[u3[t, x, y, z], y] == 0 /. y -> 10, 
   D[u3[t, x, y, z], z] == 0 /. z -> 0,
   D[u3[t, x, y, z], z] == 0 /. z -> 10,

   a1[t, x, y, z] == 0 /. x -> 0, 
   a1[t, x, y, z] == 0 /. x -> 10, 
   a1[t, x, y, z] == 0 /. y -> 0, 
   a1[t, x, y, z] == 0 /. y -> 10, 
   a1[t, x, y, z] == 0 /. z -> 0, 
   a1[t, x, y, z] == 0 /. z -> 10, 
   D[a1[t, x, y, z], x] == 0 /. x -> 0, 
   D[a1[t, x, y, z], x] == 0 /. x -> 10, 
   D[a1[t, x, y, z], y] == 0 /. y -> 0, 
   D[a1[t, x, y, z], y] == 0 /. y -> 10, 
   D[a1[t, x, y, z], z] == 0 /. z -> 0, 
   D[a1[t, x, y, z], z] == 0 /. z -> 10, 

   a2[t, x, y, z] == 0 /. x -> 0, 
   a2[t, x, y, z] == 0 /. x -> 10, 
   a2[t, x, y, z] == 0 /. y -> 0, 
   a2[t, x, y, z] == 0 /. y -> 10, 
   a2[t, x, y, z] == 0 /. z -> 0, 
   a2[t, x, y, z] == 0 /. z -> 10, 
   D[a2[t, x, y, z], x] == 0 /. x -> 0, 
   D[a2[t, x, y, z], x] == 0 /. x -> 10, 
   D[a2[t, x, y, z], y] == 0 /. y -> 0, 
   D[a2[t, x, y, z], y] == 0 /. y -> 10, 
   D[a2[t, x, y, z], z] == 0 /. z -> 0, 
   D[a2[t, x, y, z], z] == 0 /. z -> 10, 

   a3[t, x, y, z] == 0 /. x -> 0, 
   a3[t, x, y, z] == 0 /. x -> 10, 
   a3[t, x, y, z] == 0 /. y -> 0, 
   a3[t, x, y, z] == 0 /. y -> 10, 
   a3[t, x, y, z] == 0 /. z -> 0, 
   a3[t, x, y, z] == 0 /. z -> 10, 
   D[a3[t, x, y, z], x] == 0 /. x -> 0, 
   D[a3[t, x, y, z], x] == 0 /. x -> 10, 
   D[a3[t, x, y, z], y] == 0 /. y -> 0, 
   D[a3[t, x, y, z], y] == 0 /. y -> 10, 
   D[a3[t, x, y, z], z] == 0 /. z -> 0, 
   D[a3[t, x, y, z], z] == 0 /. z -> 10

   }, 
  {p, u1, u2, u3, T, phi, a1, a2, a3}, 
  {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, {z, 0, 10}]
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Scrape-n-paste your Latex back into Mathematica via ToExpression["...yourlatex...", TeXForm] returns {0,Null,ErrorBox[ErrorBox["+"]],Null,Overscript[u, \[RightVector]],Null,ErrorBox[ErrorBox["\[CenterDot]"]]...and more and more and more...}. Polite suggestion: Just paste the plain Mathematica code without any desktop publishing and without any "..." If I were to ask you a question saying I have some stuff and eqn1=0 and ... and it doesn't work, exactly what and where is my syntax error?" how could you respond?

Comment: Hi Bill! Thank you very much for the comment. I pasted the plain mathematica code now.

Comment: Peter Thanks for the code, that really helps. I don't know if it will make enough difference but you have initial conditions 0 == -1/40 AG E^(-4/(kB T[t, 0, y, z])) T[t, 0, y, z]^2, 0 == -1/40 AG E^(-4/(kB T[t, 10, y, z])) T[t, 10, y, z]^2 and if you have some information about the range of T then you might be able to simplify those. It doesn't matter, but your use of N[decimal constant] is exactly the same as just decimal constant and the method/style of your initial conditions isn't uniformly consistent across all your items. I'm still trying to find a way to get a solution out of it.

Comment: Peter On my last comment there, it seems that either T==0 or T==Infinity. Either of those bother me and might bother Mathematica. If your system can justify this I think that a condition of T==0 might be less worrysome.

Comment: Bill I see your point! Unfortunately, this boundary condition is quite central. I think about how I can change it. I also thought about only applying the math to symmetric systems and reduce the equations to 1 or 2 dimensions. That should reduce the memory usage a lot. Im sure yet, if that works...

Comment: Peter I wasn't trying to remove the boundary condition, I was just trying to simplify it and make it more understandable to Mathematica. I was also looking at the number of equations and saw that p and T appeared far fewer times and in far simpler contexts and wondered whether it might be possible to incorporate those into the other equations to simplify the problem to a point where a solution was within reach. Either that or try it with 32 gigabytes of RAM and a large swap space and wait to see what happens